# Spring mvc, why my model is not updating? how to fix ?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

using spring mvc i want to do a website showing a weather for you default location (based on ip) or if you type in address i want it to refresh based on ur address.
but when i type in it doesnt refresh why ?
all data is updated in my classes what can cause my problem and how to fix it ?

i include my controller + jsp file if you need any other please tell my i will update this question.

demo website: `http://156.17.231.132:8080/`

controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    Weather weather;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest req) {

        Language.getInstance().setLanguage(LanguageManager.getLanguage(new Locale(System.getProperty("user.language"))));
        Location location = LocationManager.getLocation(req);
        weather = WeatherManager.getWeather(location);

        model.addAttribute("location", location);
        model.addAttribute("weather", weather);
        model.addAttribute("destination", new Destination());

        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("destination") Destination destination,BindingResult result) {
        destination = DestinationManager.getDestination(destination.getAddress());
        weather = WeatherManager.getWeather(destination);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

and here is jsp file:
also why my if doesnt work here ?

```
<!doctype html>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weatherr</title>

    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offset2">
            <%--<h2>Getting current weather data</h2>--%>
            <%--<h2>http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.1&lon=17.0333&lang=en</h2>--%>
            <%--<h2>Getting forecast data every 3 hours</h2>--%>
            <%--<h2>http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=51.1&lon=17.0333&lang=en</h2>--%>
            <%--<h2>Getting daily forecast weather data - Seaching 10 days forecast by geographic coordinats </h2>--%>
            <%--<h2>http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=51.1&lon=17.0333&cnt=10&mode=json&lang=en</h2>--%>

            <core:if test="${empty destination}">
                <h2>${location.city}, ${location.countryName}</h2>
            </core:if>

            <core:if test="${not empty destination}">
                <h2>${destination.address}</h2>
            </core:if>

            <h3>${weather.dt}</h3>

            <h3><img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${weather.weatherData.icon}.png"
                     style="float:left; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; border:0" alt="weather" width="20%" height="20%"/>

                ${weather.weatherData.description}</br>

                Temp: ${weather.main.temp}&deg;C</br>

                Wind speed: ${weather.wind.speed} mps, direction ${weather.wind.deg}  </br>

                Wind gust: ${weather.wind.gust} mps</br>

                Cloudiness: ${weather.clouds}% </br>

                Atmospheric pressure: ${weather.main.pressure}hPa </br>

                Humidity: ${weather.main.humidity}%</h3>

            <form:form method="post" action="search" commandName="destination" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <form:input path="address"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn"/>
                    </form:form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain the behavior when you submit your POST form?

Comment: i will just write how i understand it works because i maybe wrong im new in spring. So whe you type some city i store it in my class Destination as addres variable then i parse useing google api latitude and longitude for that city in this object. and then i want to ubdate my weather for that cords but its not ubdating in my site

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your POST handler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(
    @ModelAttribute("destination") Destination destination,
    BindingResult result) {
    destination = DestinationManager.getDestination(destination.getAddress());
    weather = WeatherManager.getWeather(destination);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Although you have a `@ModelAttribute` for `destination` which adds the object to the model for the current request, you are performing a `redirect`. A redirect ends up sending a 302 (or 303) status code as a response with a `Location` header. When the browser receives this response, it makes a new Http request to your server at the url specified by the `Location` header. Since model attributes only live for one request, the `destination` attribute no longer exists in the model of the new request.

Regardless, you would still overwrite it with

```
model.addAttribute("destination", new Destination());
```

in your GET handler.

The solution for this is to persist the attributes for longer than 1 request. In other words, use flash attributes. Spring provides the `RedirectAttributes` class to let you do that. See it in action [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html).

If you use this solution, in your GET, I would suggest first checking if the model contains an attribute with key `destination` before you overwrite it

```
if (!model.containsAttribute("destination"))
    model.addAttribute("destination", new Destination());
```

Comment: so if i understand it correctly you suggest me to use RedirectAttributes in my GET (listUsers method)
but how i check if they exist ?

Comment: Make your POST method handler accept a `RedirectAttributes` argument. Add flash attributes to that object and redirect. Before your GET handler is executed, Spring will add those attributes to the `Model` so they will be available in your method.

Comment: like this ? `redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute(destination);` or i have also do it for weather ? or something like this ? 
        `redirectAttrs.addAttribute("id", destination.getLatitude()).addFlashAttribute("message", "Found location!");` and then do `return "redirect:/location/{id}";`

Comment: i tried the second option becous i suspect it to be the correct one but i get the exception as follow: `http://pastebin.com/e8m7ysjd`

Comment: @vardius It seems like you need a newer version of Spring to use it.

Comment: so lets try to fix it other way for example if i would like to display result in new page i mean jsp file would it be good idea or not ?
and how to do it ? do i have to or should i creat new controller for new jsp file ? and how to pass the value frome one to other ? do i need to manage session ?

Comment: @Vardius [Here's a solution](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2011/01/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web-applications/) to implementing flash attributes yourself. Instead of redirecting, you could just return `index` which will forward and render the `index.jsp` page. You would also need to set the other model attributes that page requires.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974893/spring-mvc-serving-content-twice Can you see if you can help me with updating a webpage twice?